# Visual Studio VS2019/VS2022 is there a comprehensive list of minor version platform toolsets?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019

Is there a comprehensive listing of platform toolsets and MSC_VER minor revisions?
I was digging for it today and can't find it.

Specifically I'm looking for VS2019 platform toolsets and MSC_VER corresponding to VS2019 releases 16.1.6 and 16.5.4.  But a comphrehensive list will work better moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

The Best information I found is at this link.
[Visual Studio 2019 Build List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history)
It's not ideal as it doesn't tie each one to a platform toolset.
That appears to be due to platform toolsets only existing for the first digit of minor rev, not second.  So you can't be 100% sure the platform toolset will 100% match your specific downloaded release without testing.
Users can confirm a 100% match by adding the -Bv switch to the compiler options, this will dump Build versions for the compiler.  This covers the build of the compiler/linker tools, but the *.h files and runtime libraries could be different possibly.  Not sure.

So far this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B) link contains a portion of the information.  It only gets a partial list of minor revisions.  For example 16.1 and 16.5 are listed but not 16.1.6, 16.5.4  but its close.  My assumption is that the platform toolset for Visual Studio 16.1 would be v14.21.
I also show the Visual Studio 2019 installer which only provides the same level of detail.

[image: Partial Table]
[image: Visual Studio Installer]

From this I conclude that it is *NOT* possible to exactly match release 16.1.6, or 16.5.4 unless these are the *LAST* minor releases of the software.  It's impossible to know that because there is no comprehensive list.  So I can't say for sure that platform toolset 16.1 or 16.5 EXACTLY matches 16.1.6 or 16.5.4 because there is no comprehensive listing.